# How to call a named variable in a user-defined formula? Not recognized using dplyr::summarise()

Tags: r, function, dplyr, roc

I am trying to create a function to extraction of confidence intervals for 2 named variables of an 'area under the curve' estimate using the `ci.auc()` function from the `pROC` package, but it produces and error:
`Error in model.frame.default(formula = anchor, data = namedvar1, : 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list`  .
**How to can Ifix this? Is there a better way to specify which dataframe to draw the named variables from?**

The original code works fine:

```
library(pROC)

df <- structure(list(anchor1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), namedvar1 = c(0.603, 
-0.006, 0, 0.263, 0, -0.089), namedvar2 = c(0.150346263678009, 
0.388250731888, -0.2579633906095, 0.2562039253, 0.139948502022, 
-0.267652844)), row.names = c(6L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 19L, 29L), class = "data.frame")


# Base example with to extract CI bounds & estimate
 as.numeric (ci.auc ( roc (df$anchor1, df$namedvar1, smooth = FALSE,         
                         direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) )

# Output looks good:
[1] 0.2908208 0.7777778 1.0000000
```

Great, so I integate the above into my function (where I want to do it for multiple named vars):

```
### CREATE FUNC TO CALCULATE AUC and 95% CIs

new_roc <- function( df, anchor, na.rm = T) {
  anchor <- enquo(anchor)

  # Calculate and save this information as an object
  dplyr::summarise(df, 
                   # ci.auc() & roc() are from pROC package
                   "Var1 AUC CIs"  = as.numeric (ci.auc (roc (anchor, namedvar1, smooth = FALSE,         
                                                                 direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) ),
                   "Var2 AUC CIs"  = as.numeric (ci.auc (roc (anchor, namedvar2, smooth = FALSE, 
                                                                 direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) )
  ) 
}
```

But when I test it out, I get an error!

```
# Try the function

new_roc(df, anchor1 )

# Error output: 
`Error in model.frame.default(formula = anchor, data = namedvar1,  :'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list`
```

I tried `class(df)` and it's indeed a `data.frame` so not sure what the issue is.

To try to isolate the problem, I tried inner code but by specifying the dataframe first -  Does not work:

```
 # Doesn't work to pipe the df
df %>% 
  as.numeric (ci.auc (roc (anchor1, namedvar1, smooth = FALSE,         
                                        direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) )
  
## Produces error

Error in roc(anchor1, namedvar1, smooth = FALSE, direction = "<",  : 
  object 'anchor1' not found
```

**Maybe I am unnecessarily using dplyr? Is there a different way to specify which dataframe to draw the named variables from? Thanks!**

I've also tried to ditch dplyr and call the dataframe directly, but doesn't work either:

```
new_roc <- function( df, anchor, na.rm = T) {
  anchor <- enquo(anchor)

  # Calculate and save this information as an object
                   # ci.auc() & roc() are from pROC package
                   "Var1 AUC CIs"  = as.numeric (ci.auc (roc (data[[anchor], data[[namedvar1], smooth = FALSE,         
                                                                 direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) ),
                   "Var2 AUC CIs"  = as.numeric (ci.auc (roc (data[[anchor], data[[namedvar2], smooth = FALSE, 
                                                                 direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) )
  ) 
}

# Produces a different Error:
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  invalid subscript type 'language'
```

Comment: IIn the input data, the column name is just `anchor`

Comment: Thanks @akrun , I've updated the input data to 'anchor1' to match the rest of the code. The 'anchor1' is an example of the anchor to be specified when actually using the formula.

Comment: Please test the function in my solution

Comment: Clarifying : the solution doesn't quite work - when I use the updated input data with the column name as anchor1 and then call new_roc(df, anchor1) , I get the error Error: Column `Var1 AUC CIs` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3 '  

I tried replacing with {{namedvar1}} and {{namedvar2}} instead of curly brackets around {{anchor}} in your solution, but got Error in (function (arg)  : object 'namedvar1' not found '.

Comment: It is working fine with your data as I showed below.  The namedvar1 and namedvar2 are actual column names, you don't need to replace with `{{`. Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: Is this on the same data in your post?  I am getting the expected output

Comment: I tested this on `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.4’`

Comment: Ahhhh I have ```packageVersion('dplyr')  [1] ‘0.8.5’``` . Will reinstall dplyr

Comment: It won't work with `0.8.5` as `{{}}` was introduced around 1.0

Comment: Updated my dplyr and now your solution works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `!!` for evaluation with `enquo` or can modify that to `{{}}`

```
new_roc <- function( df, anchor, na.rm = TRUE) {



      dplyr::summarise(df, 
             
             `Var1 AUC CIs`  = as.numeric (ci.auc (roc ({{anchor}},
                  namedvar1, smooth = FALSE,         
                    direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) ),
               `Var2 AUC CIs`  = as.numeric (ci.auc (roc ({{anchor}},
               namedvar2, smooth = FALSE, 
                  direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) )
     ) 
  }
```

-testing

```
new_roc(df, anchor1)
#Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#  Var1 AUC CIs Var2 AUC CIs
#1    0.2908208    0.0000000
#2    0.7777778    0.3333333
#3    1.0000000    0.9866547
```

which is the same as

```
as.numeric (ci.auc ( roc (df$anchor1, df$namedvar1, smooth = FALSE,         
                         direction = "<" ,ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE )  ) )
#Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#[1] 0.2908208 0.7777778 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `dplyr` methods try :

```
library(pROC)

new_roc <- function( df, anchor) {
  
data.frame(Var1_AUC_CIs = as.numeric(ci.auc(roc(df[[anchor]], df$namedvar1, smooth = FALSE, direction = "<",
                          ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE))), 
           Var2_AUC_CIs = as.numeric(ci.auc(roc(df[[anchor]], df$namedvar2, smooth = FALSE, direction = "<",
                          ci = TRUE, boot.stratified = TRUE)))) 
}
new_roc(df, 'anchor1')

#  Var1_AUC_CIs Var2_AUC_CIs
#1    0.2908208    0.0000000
#2    0.7777778    0.3333333
#3    1.0000000    0.9866547
```